# How to exclude tags from a div statement

Tags: html, tags

I am trying to make a div tag that surrounds everything but the `<p>` tags. Is there any way to exclude a certain or certain tags? Thanks for the help.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

<body>

<div id='main'>

<h1>FREE Python programs!</h1>

<h3><p>You're saying to yourself "I could use a handy little program that does this
" or "I need a better calculator than Windows has provided me!" THIS IS THE SITE YOU'VE      BEEN LOOKING FOR! Just email me at:</p></h3> 

<a href="mailto:benevedeselias@gmail.com" target="_blank">Python Program Maker</a>

<h3><p>And I'll respond as fast as I can!</p></h3>
<p>This is my portfolio of very small applications:</p>

<a href="portfolio.zip">Portfolio Download</a>

<p>If you would like to subscribe to my Python Mailing list, click on the link above to    shoot me an email. Please have the subject be "Add to mailing list". All this mailing list    would do is send you updates to my website, python programs, or portfolio. This would mean   a great lot to me if you did.</p>

<p>These links provide more information about each piece in my portfolio:</p>

<a href='CardDrawer.html'>Card Drawer</a>
<a href='BlockGame.html'>Block Game</a>
<a href='Dice.html'>Dice</a>
<a href='SecretNumber.html'>Secret Number</a>

<p>If you would like to learn python yourself, I have started a video tutorial series.     Here is the first one:</p>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/STe5x9V8kbk?rel=0"    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>



</body>

</head>
```

All that I am attempting to do is to avoid having to have multiple div tags breaking at every p tag and start again after it.

Comment: What's the *starting* HTML (the 'input') and what HTML do you want to *end* with (the 'output')? And, really, you'll need JavaScript (or a JavaScript library) to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really do not understand what you mean, but I can try:

You can give your `<p>` tags their own classes and/or id's. you can make a class/id for it in your css and that way they will ignore the css given to your div. (I hope this is what you mean)

so you get:

```
<p class="yourclass">text</p>
```

You can even give them a different background color. If you don't want to have them in your div, simply place them outside of it. There is not much benefit to it though...

If you mean you want to end the div with every one, that's what you have to do though. No way around it.

Comment: I believe it only understands classes. so instead of # you make a .classname in your css and use "class="classname" instead of "id="something"".

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to not have the div surrounding the p tags?

With one div tag that contains p tags you should be able to style everything in CSS